# Payment Gateway integration to Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, payment-gateway

Can anyone share a reference link or an article which demonstrate the integration of Payment gateway to Hyperledger Fabric solution. What would be the best possible approach for this? Design diagram of integration will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The right question would be
***how to store payments' information on the Fabric. Think of blockchain as secure storage rather than a smart worker***
Now to answer this question you need to see the payment gateway integration with whatever technology you are building your application in and then when payment is done you can pass its information to fabric contract through Api where you should have a chaincode that has functions to store information on fabric or do whatever else you want to do with that data.